# Why _FileName is not taken while writing a store procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I just created a stored procedure as follows

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `db_uspaybo`.`uspACHInsertMaster` (_ID int,
_FedTaxId varchar(9),
_FileName varchar(128), //Raising an error
_FileData longblob,
_DateTime timestamp)
 BEGIN

  insert into tblachmaster(ID,FedTaxId,FileName,File_Data,Date_Time)values(
 _ID,_FedTaxId,_FileName,_FileData,_DateTime);
```

END

I really wonder why at `_FileName` it is causing an error. can any one give an explanation

Comment: What error do you get? And why do you use _FileName in one place and _FName in another?

Comment: even if i take the same i am unable to run the routine successfully

Comment: Really, saying any kind of code "causes an error" is like calling the car shop saying "my car doesn't work" without mentioning it got no engine. Provide the error message you are getting and we all might find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL parser treats `_FileName` as a reserved word. Consider either using ` to escape it or changing it to a non-reserved word.

Consider checking for [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) when having seemingly random errors.